# Date time conversion in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am filling a text box from database, where I need to show only the date part. So I am formatting the date time like this,

```
if(ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["AuditDate"].ToString()!="")
                   txtAuditDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["AuditDate"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

This is working fine, now I need to send this text box data to database again in date format.

So I am trying to format the text box like this,

```
Convert.ToDateTime(txtAuditDate.Text)
```

But I am getting error.

From database I am getting the date like this 
    "1/8/2014 12:00:00 AM"
And after first format in my text box I am getting the date like this 
    "08/01/2014"
After that 2nd conversion getting failed.

Please someone help me.
Thanks in advance Gulrej Ali

Comment: Gulrej provide some sample date that you are unable to parse.

Comment: As usual, saying _getting error_ is not the best hint to the actual error

Comment: I have edited my question and given the dates...please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [DateTime.ParseExact()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and pass it the format you have used while assign date time to `text box` that is `"dd/MM/yyyy"`.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(txtAuditDate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent using the specified format and culture-specific
>   format information. The format of the string representation must match
>   the specified format exactly, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)